# Tikz: change position of text in a subgraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I'm trying to draw subgraphs and DAGs with the new Tikz feature, however I'm running into an issue to move the text of the subgraph to somewhere where it does not overlap.

Ideally, in the example below, I would like to shift the "in(S)" text to the right, but I have no idea how to do this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{input}=[circle, thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=5mm]
\tikzstyle{fixed}=[rectangle,thick,draw=black!75, fill=black!20,minimum size=6mm]
\tikzstyle{bitwise}=[fixed, draw=green!75, fill=green!20]
\tikzstyle{sub}=[draw, rectangle, fill=red!30, opacity=.2]

\tikz \graph [layered layout, nodes={bitwise}, level sep=1cm] {
{{{a[input], b[input]} -> 1, c[input]} -> 3, {{c, {d[input], e[input]} -> 2} -> 4}} -> 6;
{f[input], 2 -> 5[fixed]} -> 7;
{5, g[input]} -> 8;
S[sub] // {3, 4, 6};
$in(S)$[sub] // {1, c, 2}
};

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You may want to reconsider your labeling. If you add the labeling of  "in(S)" and "S" to the actual nodes, it might be easier to make sure the label positions is the way you want it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `$in(S)$[sub] // {1, c, 2}`, you specify a subgraph, which is described in section 27.10.1 (Sublayouts) of the [Ti*k*Z manual (version 3.0.1a)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). As shown there, a subgraph is drawn with

```
// [layout options]{sublayout}
```

You can specify the position of the subgraph text (in your case `$in(S)$`) with either

- `subgraph text top=<text alignment options>` (place text at the top of the subgraph).
- `subgraph text bottom=<text alignment options>` (place text at the bottom of the subgraph)`.

Here, `<text alignment options>` can be any of the alignments you use in Ti*k*Z, e.g.

```
subgraph text top={align=right}
subgraph text top=text centered
```

With `text centered`, the subgraph title is placed quite nicely:

[image: result]

Comment: I had read the sublayout part, but i had no idea there existed a "subgraph text top" property..

Thanks a lot for this very in-depth answer !

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post this as a comment but it was simple enough to generate an example from your MWE. One may also label subgraphs placing the tag outside of the bounding box as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{input}=[circle, thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=5mm]
\tikzstyle{fixed}=[rectangle,thick,draw=black!75, fill=black!20,minimum size=6mm]
\tikzstyle{bitwise}=[fixed, draw=green!75, fill=green!20]
\tikzstyle{sub}=[draw, rectangle, fill=red!30, opacity=.2]

\tikz \graph [layered layout, nodes={bitwise}, level sep=1cm] 
{
 {{{a[input], b[input]} -> 1, c[input]} -> 3, {{c, {d[input], e[input]} -> 2} -> 4}} -> 6;
 {f[input], 2 -> 5[fixed]} -> 7;
 {5, g[input]} -> 8;
 / [label = left:S,sub]       // {3, 4, 6};
 / [label = left:$in(S)$,sub] // {1, c, 2}
};

\end{document}
```

[image: Text as labels rather then within nodes]